# Gnome-40.4 Wi-Fi icon it's unclear and not it's showing the signal strength anymore

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, network-interface, graphics

#### Affected version

I'm running ArcoLinux with Gnome 40.4 on Xorg with Nvidia as my graphic card.
I've also upgraded to Gnome 41 and I've experienced the same thing. No difference there. Still, currently I'm back to v40.4.

#### Bug summary

What I think it's happening is that there's an error with some gnome icons or nm-applet. All this I've suddenly experienced after updating and rebooting around 11 November.

#### What happened

It's not showing the Wi-Fi signal like it had before with those small lines and you can see that it's not too clear.
You can clearly see that this is not supposed to happen. It's supposed to show on the signal strength
It's pretty useless there now if this is the new normal.So how can be fixed?
I tried reinstalling the OS and it got me to the same thing.

#### What did you expect to happen

It should look like this everywhere
[image: Pic]

#### Relevant logs, screenshots, screencasts etc.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue Solved

Here's how I resolved the Wi-Fi icon issue in Gnome-40.4:

Initially, I encountered this problem while customizing themes using Gnome Tweaks; the Wi-Fi icon's signal strength wasn't displaying correctly. After some investigation, I discovered that the issue was related to the icon theme I was using, specifically ArcoLinux's `sardi-icon-theme`.

To fix the problem, I took the following steps:

- I switched back to using the default themes that come pre-installed with the Gnome Desktop Environment - the Wi-Fi icon appeared normally with these themes.
- I suspected that the `sardi-icon-theme` might be missing some dependencies or configurations required for the Wi-Fi icon to display correctly.
- To address this, I installed additional icon themes using the command:

  ```shell
  pacman -S gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-icon-theme mate-icon-theme deepin-icon-theme
  ```

After installing these themes, I returned to Gnome Tweaks and continued customizing.  ArcoLinux's `sardi-icon-theme` now worked as expected and the Wi-Fi icon displayed properly.

### This is how it looks now, after these fixes:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed the problem and your working solution (high among the Google hits) with switching back to e.g.:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS x86_64 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Pocillo-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
```

Thanks!
(Still, it is a Gnome/Tweaks bug...)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).